# (dynamic) Rails model (object) parameters (values) through has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a multiple models (ie. tires and rims). Multiple models have multiple parameters (like color, size, type, etc.)

I have this:

```
Parameter:
  belongs_to :tires
  belongs_to :rims
ParameterValue:
  belongs_to :parameter
  belongs_to :tires, :through => :parameter
  belongs_to :rims, :through => :parameter
Tire:
  has_many :parameters
Rim:
  has_many :parameters
```

Here goes the problem. Multiple models can have same parameters-value pairs so creating separate models like RimParameterValue and TireParameterValue isn't optimal, IMO.

Can I create a dynamic

```
#<ParameterValue object_model: 'rim', object_id: 1542, parameter_id: 15674, value: 'Yes'>
```

instead of

```
#<RimParameter rim_id: 1542, parameter_id: 15674, value: 'Yes'>
```

?

Additionally, is there any ActiveRecord sorcery that could allow me to implement something like Tire.compatible_rims which would return only those parameter union (bead_diameter, width) has the same values?

Comment: You are looking for polymorphic associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: While polymorphs will fix here determine how many of these polymophic models there will be before making the change. If it will always be 2 then I would just leave them as separate models. My general rule of thumb is less than 3 models and this will never change then implement individual models 4 or more models or the need to add others quickly polymorphism

Comment: There will be about 30 models. Let's say: Tires, rims, brake pads, fluids, etc. etc...

Comment: What about the last paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use polymorphic association as follows:

```
# Parameter.rb
belongs_to :abc, polymorphic: true

# Migration file for parameters
t.references :abc, polymorphic: true

# Tire.rb
has_many :parameters, as: :abc

# Rim.rb
has_many :parameters, as: :abc
```

Now parameters can be accessed as @tire.parameters or @rim.parameters.